# How do I continue to receive timed interrupts in an embedded C while loop?

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I have a need for an embedded device to stay in a function for one half a second to allow another device to catch up. I used the 1 millisecond timer(r_cg_cmt.c for Renesas IAR IDE) and had a static volatile int delay_time to increment once every 1 millisecond timed interrupt.
using the code:

```
//counter.c

 //on 1 mS timed interrupt
 gen_purpose_1ms_couter();

 void gen_purpose_1ms_couter_reset( void ){ 
   gen_c->count = 0;
  }


void gen_purpose_1ms_couter( void ){ 
  gen_c->count++;
 } 


//source_file.h

struct gen_counter {
  unsigned int count;
};

extern struct gen_counter *gen_c;

//source_file.c
#include "counter.h"

struct gen_counter *gen_c;

 gen_purpose_1ms_couter_reset();
 while(1){
   if(gen_c->count > 500){
      break;
   }
 }
```

However this cause the processor (RX231) to stay in the while loop and NOT execute any timed interrupts. Can anyone explain how I can stay in a function for a give amount of time?

Comment: You have asked the exact same question last week, and got comments indicating what is wrong with the question. Why are you reposting it without fixing?

Comment: I'm posting an updated version after several people pointed out some errors.

Comment: I have no knowledge of the system your are using but from the embedded systems I have been working with I seem to recall that functions used as interrupt handlers should be marked with the keyword "interrupt". This was needed in order to make the compiler generate the code for acknowledge interrupt and re-enable interrupt. Not sure this helps at all. BTW: How are `struct gen_counter` defined?

Comment: BTW: What is the purpose of these lines: ` //on 1 mS timed interrupt
 gen_purpose_1ms_couter();` Seems strange to me. Is this some `weak` function overwrite?

Comment: OT: `couter` --> `counter`?

Comment: What is a _"timed interrupt"_? Do you simply mean _"timer interrupt"_? Your while top is tot preventing interrupts. You have not shown the interrupt code or timer or interrupt controller setup. You have also _described_ code that you have not posted. If you can see all the code, and still not see the problem, how do you expect anyone to diagnose the issue from mere fragments?  For example what if anything is calling gen_purpose_1ms_couter()?

Comment: Please fix the first question by editing, instead of posting the same question one more time.

Comment: There is a 1 millisecond timed interrupt that runs within the code. I am not sure what a "Weak" function overwrite is... I will edit again to attempt to make it easier to understand. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a complete example but here are a few possible reasons your code is not working as expected.

1. The timer isn't configured/enabled correctly.
2. The timer interrupt isn't enabled correctly.
3. The interrupt handler isn't registered correctly.
4. The while-loop has been optimized and `gen-c->count` is not re-read each iteration because it is not declared volatile.

Does a break point in `gen_purpose_1ms_couter` ever hit?  If not then the timer or interrupt is not setup correctly.

Does your code start to work if you disable optimizations?  If so then `genc->count` needs to be declared volatile.

Comment: Thank you for your response the 1mS timer hits as it should during normal operation. This delay is within an interrupt which I am just now told is a very bad idea as interrupts should be very fast. I moved it to simply setting a flag and  once the interrupt finishes it starts the delay.  This was mostly a rookie mistake but thank you for your help. It is appreciated.

Comment: @WilliamDussault Not only is it a bad idea to have a delay inside an interrupt: other interrupts are disabled when you execute an ISR, so the timer interrupt cannot execute. You've created a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks. I spent a few hours digging through the data sheet trying to cement the fact that I deadlocked the processor.